# Parse info from bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to parse out certain information from a `bash` script on `Ubuntu`

I'm having a bash script execute every x seconds which does write:

`forever list`

this response from that command looks like this:

```
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command         script                            forever pid   logfile                 uptime        
data:    [0] _1b2 /usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/node/server.js 28968   28970 /root/.forever/_1b2.log 0:0:17:17.233
```

I want to parse out the location of the logfile `/root/.forever/_1b2.log`

Any ideas how to accomplish this with bash?

Answer (score 1):

Two of the many `awk` variations to solve this issue:

```
# most basic
command | awk 'NR==3{ print $8 }' data
```

```
# a little bit more robust:
command | awk '$1=="data:" && $2=="[0]" { print $8 }' data
#                             ^^^^^^^^^
#             here I filter on the "[0]" text, but depending your needs
#             you might want to use $3=="_1b2" or $4=="/usr/bin/nodejs"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below GNU and basic sed commands,

```
$ command | sed -nr 's/^.* (\S+) [0-9]+:[0-9]+\S+$/\1/p' 
/root/.forever/_1b2.log
$ command | sed -n 's/^.* \(\S\+\) [0-9]\+:[0-9]\+\S\+$/\1/p' 
/root/.forever/_1b2.log
```

It prints only the non-space characters which is followed by a space + one or more digits + `:` symbol + one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could `grep` the line(s) you're looking for and pipe the output to `awk`:

```
forever list | grep "\.log" | awk '{print $4}'
```

This will find all processes with a .log file, and print the log file's location (4th column).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the logfile is in `/root/.forever` directory, you can use `grep` this regex:

```
forever list |  grep -o "/root/\.forever/.*\.log"
```

Comment: How do can I use the output as a variable to show the file output? like `less $varContainingFile`

Comment: Use `less "$(forever list |  grep -o "/root/\.forever/.*\.log")"` (yes, the nested double quotes are intentional)